# Hadoop Impala 1.3.1 and Open Socket error

Tags: sockets, hadoop, impala

We just upgraded Impala from 1.2.4 -> 1.3.1 and CDH from 4.6 -> 4.7 and start getting Write problems (Read is ok):

When trying to create table – it gives socket error:

> create table test_5 (x int, y string);
>   Query: create table test_5 (x int, y string)
>   Application Exception : Called write on non-open socket

Same happens when trying to refresh tables:

> invalidate metadata;
>   Query: invalidate metadata
>   Application Exception : Called write on non-open socket

Anyone had this experience? 
What should be modified in order to fix?

thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

Please check if catalogd is running properly in the server where catalog service should run by

```
ps -elf | grep catalogd
```

next check properly configured ports to catalogd in all servers where impalad is running

check file `/etc/default/impala` for `IMPALA_SERVER_ARGS="catalog_service_host=${CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST}"`

make sure that variable `CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST` is set properly to server where catalog is running.